# Creating Triggers in .sql file gives error in db2

Tags: db2

I have 3 triggers in a .sql file.

```
CREATE TRIGGER NEW_HIRED
     AFTER INSERT ON EMPLOYEE
     FOR EACH ROW
     UPDATE COMPANY_STATS SET NBEMP = NBEMP + 1;

CREATE TRIGGER FORMER_EMP
     AFTER DELETE ON EMPLOYEE
     FOR EACH ROW
     UPDATE COMPANY_STATS SET NBEMP = NBEMP - 1;

CREATE TRIGGER FORMER_EMP1
     AFTER DELETE ON EMPLOYEE
     FOR EACH ROW
     UPDATE COMPANY_STATS SET NBEMP = NBEMP - 1;
```

When I run those, it gives me below error:

> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
>   valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
>   SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "
>   NBEMP".  Expected tokens may include:  "".  LINE 
>   NUMBER=1.  SQLSTATE=42601

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.!

Comment: The error message does not seem to match your code: there is no string `d' , NBEMP )`. Your code contains a syntax error, but it's a bit hard to debug the code that one cannot see.

Comment: Sorry about that. There is no d in the error. That was a typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: What about the closing parenthesis? Unless you show the _actual_ code and _actual_ error message, I doubt anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: I just have these 3 trigger statements in the fil eand I have pasted the error message also the one which I have got. What do you mean by closing parenthesis? Am I missing those in my trigger stmts?

Comment: By the closing parenthesis I mean the symbol that looks like `)`, which, according to the error message, is part of your code. However, in the code you published there isn't a single parenthesis, opening or closing.

Comment: AFAIK can tell there is nothing wrong with your triggers (I don't understand why you have two triggers for delete though). Can you provide table definitions and some sample data that illustrates the problem? I created a table like `create table company_stats (nbemp int); insert into company_stats (select count(1) from employee)` and then created your triggers and it worked fine (although it decreases nbemp twice for each delete).

Comment: Did you try changing what the error message says is wrong? It says `"END-OF-STATEMENT" was found` and that's an error. Remove the`;` that ends the statement and try running one statement by itself in a .SQL file.